# Perl json array using to_json

Tags: json, perl

I have a a following data that I want to convert it to JSON using to_json.

The data is a

```
[  
  {"key":"firstname", "val":"Scott"},
  {"key":"age",       "val":"old"},
  {"key":"haircolor", "val":"na"},
]
```

I usually use perl hash to build my json and use to_json for conversion. But for this json array for each iterm I have no key. So how can I use to_json for conversion.

e.g.

```
  my %data = (
       "key" => "firstname", 
       "val" => "Scott",
        ...
   )
```

Thanks,

P.S. I do not want to make a string and convert it to json. But if I must, I will. :-)

Comment: The data you have already is JSON (except for the trailing comma, which I don't think is valid).  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @EricStrom - The trailing comma technically isn't valid, but--assuming the OP is using the `JSON` module--[it can be parsed when `relaxed` is enabled](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm#relaxed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $data=[
           {  key  => "firstname", 'val' ,  "Scott" },
           { "key" => "age",       "val" => "old"   },
           { 'key',   'haircolor',  val  => "na"    },
         ];
```

```
my @data = (
  { key => "firstname", val => "Scott" },
  { key => "age",       val => "old"   },
  { key => 'haircolor', val => "na"    },
);
```